# How to check wifi connection duration in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, event-log

I am using windows 10 on my computer system and I would like to know when did I connect and disconnect my WIFI connection. Is it possible to obtain that record in Events log? If not where can I find it?

Answer (score 0):

You could check the following  log in the Event Viewer by navigating to :

Applications and Services Logs/Microsoft/Windows/UniversalTelemetryClient/Operational

Look for event ID 55. It displays "Is the Internet available:" followed by true or false.

Hope it helps.